# Query to remove the specific length character words in a string?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Need a query to replace the specific length character words like on,in,to,if...(0 to 2 character length word).

```
SELECT content AS NormalText, 
LOWER(replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(content, '[^A-Za-z0-9]', '') , ' ','')) AS RegexText 
FROM `table`
```

but before the above query, 2 length characters has to be removed. Only grater than 2 length characters should be shown.

Comment: Not a task for which sql is best primed, I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below query to replace the 2 character words with empty space in a sentence. It will show you only the words in the sentence having characters greater than two. Hope it helps you.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(columnname,' [a-z]{0,2} ','') FROM `tablename` WHERE condition
```

Comment: `' [a-z]{0,2} '` -> `'\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}]\b'`